# Selenium unhide elements C#

Tags: c#, selenium

I have Menu Group:

```
<div class="menuGroup">
```

Some of this div contain class which hide or show menu contents

```
class="toggleMenuChildren">
```

When you click on it, it change on

```
class="toggleMenuChildren opened">
```

So I want show all content from menu (click on all classes `toggleMenuChildren`) to show it.

I try this

```
IWebElement zi = driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("toggleMenuChildren"));
            zi.Click();
```

But this opened (unhide) just first element, and if you call it again then hide content. How I can show all content (click on all elements) ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use xpath - `//div[contains(@class,'toggleMenuChildren') and not(contains(@class,'opened'))]`

(sorry it is in java)

```
List<WebElement> allElements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'toggleMenuChildren') and not(contains(@class,'opened'))]"));
for(WebElement ele: allElements){
 ele.click;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use hover to show all the information under toggleMenuChildren class

```
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
IWebElement menuHoverLink =
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@class='toggleMenuChildren']"));
actions.MoveToElement(menuHoverLink);
actions.Build().Perform();

//That is the elements under the toggleMenuChildren class that you can use
driver.FindElement(By.PartialLinkText("...")).Click();
```

after perform() line all the elements will be unhided .